# How to run a block of MSSQL code with multiple int variable values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, int

How do I run a block of MSSQL code by passing three int values (40,41,42) in the INT variable @Sector & run the block three times with these values.

(Block of MSSQL Code that needs an int variable @Sector)

Comment: Could you please provide some code and/or query?

Comment: You, generally, don't. If possible, you re-write your "block of code" so that it can work with *sets* of data, and then you pass it a *set*  (a.k.a table) containing 3 rows with the necessary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you cannot create batch logic, the following cursor is generally how you'd approach this problem.

```
DECLARE @Sectors TABLE ( Sector INT );

INSERT INTO @Sectors VALUES (40), (41), (42);

DECLARE @Sector INT;
DECLARE Sectors CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        Sector
    FROM @Sectors;

OPEN Sectors;
FETCH Sectors INTO @Sector;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- Do something here that cannot be batched
    PRINT @Sector;

    FETCH Sectors INTO @Sector;
END

CLOSE Sectors;
DEALLOCATE Sectors;
```

Comment: Thanks jtimperley for taking the time to answer my question. I like your solution.